# Stop chrome extension from executing based on condition

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome extension that I'm developing requires users to authenticate with Gmail account.

However, if a user doesn't want to authorize, I've stopped the authorization window from appearing. However, some background scripts seem to be running. How do I make sure that the extension stops functioning completely?

Answer (score 0):

You must initiate your extension in a callback called when the user is authenticated. For example, using oAuth2:

```
function onAuthorized() {

var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo';
var request = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'parameters': {
        'alt': 'json'
    }
};

// Declare the callback
oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, callback, request);
```

};

and the callback:

```
function callback(resp, xhr) {
    // ... Process text response ...

    }).done(function (data) {
        // Your used is authenticated... 
        // ==>Init your extension HERE


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) with `"persistent": false` will be unloaded after a few seconds of inactivity. Stop doing work and the right thing will happen.